# Can one bypass silverlight for watching videos?

Tags: silverlight, video-streaming, bypass

There is this [one site](http://mmajunkie.com/news/22302/watch-todays-ufc-126-press-conference-live-on-mmajunkie-com-at-4-p-m-et.mma) that is using Silverlight to stream videos. I dislike Silverlight a lot, because the plugin is always "not up-to date" and I need to update it all the time.

Is there any way to bypass the silverlight to watch that videos?

Comment: You need to update it all the time? Shouldn't happen. The newest is 4.0, so there were only 4 major revisions. Does http://metalgearsonic.de/WebcamPhoto say the same? If yes... Do you use Firefox? I've heard of others using Firefox with the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried with a different browser ?

Comment: No plug in is always up to date, they all require updating occasionally. You might edit your post to include the Browser you are using.

Comment: @Moab no, most plugin are always up to date, the silverlight is never up to date.

Comment: What browser is it? IE, Firefox, Chrome?

Comment: @Moab I use FF, but its browser agnostic since I can easly switch.

Comment: I think you are right it just uses the silverlight already installed for windows, which is updated using Windows updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Silverlight is not installed on your computer, some websites detect this and offer you streaming video in another format, such as Flash or Quicktime. But this of course entirely depends on these websites willing to make the effort.

The only other solution is to use an alternative player software. However, I don't see the difference between installing Silverlight and installing another software that implicitly contains Silverlight.